Villager won't turn to zombie
I'm trying to convert a villager in Minecraft 1.21 into a zombie and the zombie just keeps killing the villager.

We need more details. How are you trying to convert the villager?

Well, Pengu Roxy said, "the zombie just keeps killing the villager," which means Pengu has a zombie attempting to "zombify" the Villager. Of course it makes sense that the question isn't quite clear, but there is that.

A zombie can only convert a villager if the difficulty is set to Hard, and on Normal it only has a 50% chance. Otherwise, it'll just kill the villager as per usual.
